# wl18xx driver load fail

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, beaglebone

I am having problems with my beaglebone green wireless wifi driver.

When I am booting, I can get the following messages from my UART console:

```
wl18xx_driver wl18xx.0.auto: Direct firmware load for ti-connectivity/wl1271-nvs.bin failed with error -2
wl18xx_driver wl18xx.0.auto: Direct firmware load for ti-connectivity/wl18xx-conf.bin failed with error -2
wlcore: ERROR could not get configuration binary ti-connectivity/wl18xx-conf.bin: -2
wlcore: WARNING falling back to default config
wlcore: wl18xx HW: 183x or 180x, PG 2.2 (ROM 0x11)
wlcore: loaded
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
wl18xx_driver wl18xx.0.auto: Direct firmware load for ti-connectivity/wl18xx-fw-4.bin failed with error -2
wlcore: ERROR could not get firmware ti-connectivity/wl18xx-fw-4.bin: -2
wl18xx_driver wl18xx.0.auto: Direct firmware load for ti-connectivity/wl18xx-fw-4.bin failed with error -2
wlcore: ERROR could not get firmware ti-connectivity/wl18xx-fw-4.bin: -2
wl18xx_driver wl18xx.0.auto: Direct firmware load for ti-connectivity/wl18xx-fw-4.bin failed with error -2
wlcore: ERROR could not get firmware ti-connectivity/wl18xx-fw-4.bin: -2
wl18xx_driver wl18xx.0.auto: Direct firmware load for ti-connectivity/wl18xx-fw-4.bin failed with error -2
wlcore: ERROR could not get firmware ti-connectivity/wl18xx-fw-4.bin: -2
wlcore: ERROR firmware boot failed despite 3 retries
```

It seems to me that the ti-connectivity files are simply missing, or that the configuration is looking for them in the wrong path.
When I run the following command:

```
ethtool -i wlan0 | grep driver
```

I get:

```
driver: wl18xx_driver
```

Which I assume means that a driver is installed for this hardware.

Since it seems that my understanding of the problem is insufficient to solve it, would someone more experienced point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your driver is not finding the firmware for your device. You can try to find them at linux firmware repository: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/

After downloading your firmware, store the fimware file(s) at /lib/firmware/ti-connectivity. If you don't have the ti-connectivity folder, you can create it.